# Twitter Typeahead Getting the dom element that was clicked

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

Is there any way to get the div element itself when a suggestion is clicked in the drop down menu from any of the events such as  before or select event handlers.

The event handlers eventTarget seem to always return the input in which the user is typing i.e. the main input for the Typeahead. We want to get the actual element that the user clicks.

We have looked in the docs and internet, and no where is this listed.

Many thanks